# Adding layout to another layout at specific place defined earlier

Tags: android, android-layout

Lets say I create a relative layout in xml file, and I put a placeholder at some location in this layout for future view.  This future view is another layout that is in another XML view. How can do that in code?I know I have to inflate the future view but when I add it to the main layout it ends up being top left corener rather than the place holder  I created for it
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any view to any place in your layout, have Parent View of view as RelativeLayout, Suppose you want to place your view at (x, y) point on screen, find out Layout's Position on screen by method:

```
View.getLocationOnScreen()
```

Lets assume we get x1, and y1, by this method.
now find out view's future (x, y) position relative to parent layout by view's absolute x, y co-ordinates - parent's absolute x1, y1. Lets assume we find difference as x2, y2.

Now Define LayoutParams of your view as below:

```
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.future_view, null);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.setMargins(x2, y2, 0, 0);


    relativeLayout.addView(v,relativeParams)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I like the idea of relative distances

Answer (score 1):

Forget placeholders, just add the view like normal and specify what params you want when you create it.

```
View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.future_view, null);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
v.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_TOP);
relativeLayout.addView(v,relativeParams)
```